# _Generic parameter beyond minimum number of arguments

Tags: c, generics, overloading, c11

I have found myself in strange situation trying to add some syntactic prettyness to some C code. I have triplets of numbers that are just structs.

```
typedef struct {int x, y, z} coord;
```

Now I have some functions that take 2 such structs as arguments. The simplest one counts the number of coordinates inside the 3D space defined two structs:

```
static inline int boxes_inside(const coord min, const coord max)
{
    return (1 + max.x - min.x) * (1 + max.y - min.y) * (1 + max.z - min.z);
}
```

I find myself pretty regularly calling it with fixed arguments, which I find to be quite ugly

```
coord foo;
/* initialize foo with something */
int n = boxes_inside((coord){.x = 0, .y = 0, .z = 0}, foo);
```

Nevermind this example being silly, it makes more sense for more complicated functions.

I thought I would use `_Generic` to pass either triplets of ints, or structs.

```
int boxes_inside_cc(const coord min, const coord max);
int boxes_inside_ci(const coord min, const int maxx, const int maxy, const int maxz);
int boxes_inside_ic(const int minx, const int miny, const int minz,  const coord max);
int boxes_inside_ii(const int minx, const int miny, const int minz, const int maxx, const int maxy, const int maxz);

#define arg1(a, ...) (a)
#define arg2(a, b ...) (b)
#define arg4(a, b, c, d, ...) (d)

#define boxes_inside(...) _Generic(arg1(__VA_ARGS__), \
        coord: _Generic(arg2(__VA_ARGS__), coord: boxes_inside_cc, int: boxes_inside_ci) \
        int: _Generic(arg4(__VA_ARGS__), coord: boxes_inside_ic, int: boxes_inside_ii) \
    )(__VA_ARGS__)
```

I thought this would be fine since "the expressions of the selections that are not chosen are are never evaluated." [(ref)](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/generic) but it turns out that since this is [done after preprocessing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30471806/gcc-e-does-not-expand-c11-generic-expressions), all macros are still expanded even in selections that are not chosen.

In particular, if I now do the following call:

```
coord min, max;
/* stuff */
int n = boxes_inside(min, max);
```

I get the problem that `arg4(__VA_ARGS__)` tries to expand more parameters than it actually has, even though this branch of the _Generic will never be evaluated later on.

So I then tried to expand the structs to, always have enough arguments:

```
#define boxes_inside_(a, b, c, d, ...) _Generic((a), \
        coord: boxes_inside_ii(a, b, c, d.x, d.y, d.z), \
        int: boxes_inside_ii(a, b, c, d, __VA_ARGS__) \
    )

#define boxes_inside(a, ...) _Generic((a), \
        coord: boxes_inside_(a.x, a.y, a.z, __VA_ARGS__) \
        int: boxes_inside_(a, __VA_ARGS__) \
    )
```

However this unsurprisingly fails with the same reason: both branches expand the other macro, in particular `boxes_inside(min, max)` still expands to `boxes_inside_(min max)` on the branch we already know won't be used.

So is there a way around this? Or are `_Generic` expressions basically useless if you want to test a parameter that's beyond the minimal number of parameters you might use?

Comment: I'm almost afraid to suggest putting [Boost.PP](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/master/libs/preprocessor/doc/ref/overload.html) magic around this stuff, but you're a coffee machine so you probably know what you are doing.

Comment: @Quentin I could indeed always start by [overloading the macro on the number of arguments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11761703/overloading-macro-on-number-of-arguments), only then splitting on types with _Generic, which is probably close to what the boost preprocessor library does anyway. But it's more that I'm baffled at _Generic's limitations for my first time using it, and wondering if I didn't overlook something stupid...

Comment: I think this approach can't work; all branches of a generic have to not have constraint violations even if they aren't selected

Comment: The core problem is that _Generic is a primary expression and evaluated after the pre-processor. As for how to solve the actual problem here, simply create a consistent, sound API. Regardless of popular belief, function overloading never made much sense in any programming language. If your function takes 6 integers you can easily create a conversion routine or macro that transforms a `coord` struct into 3 integers. Passing structs by value is usually not a good idea.

Comment: @Lundin This simple inline function takes them by value, most functions by pointer. Makes it even more annoying to pass a constant value, tbh. But you're right, overloading doesn't play a much bigger goal than removing some clutter here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, here goes what we discussed in the comments, even though it is not really satisfying, since it's not really an elegant solution.

- First, define `boxes_inside_X` for every `X` being an acceptable number of arguments, using `_Generic` when necessary.
- Then overload the macro by pasting the number of arguments after it (or using [Boost.PP](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/master/libs/preprocessor/doc/ref/overload.html) as suggested by [Quentin](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40455271/generic-parameter-beyond-minimum-number-of-arguments/40494745#comment68156300_40455271)).

```
/* macros that can be reused (possibly with more arguments) */
#define paste2(a, b) a ## b
#define paste(a, b) paste2(a, b)
#define get_seventh(_1, _2, _3, _4, _5, _6, this_one, ...) this_one
#define get_suffix(...) get_seventh(__VA_ARGS__, _6, _5, _4, _3, _2, _1)

/* define all variants with number of arguments suffix */
int boxes_inside_2(const coord min, const coord max);
int boxes_inside_6(const int minx, const int miny, const int minz, const int maxx, const int maxy, const int maxz);

/* make it a _Generic, if several functions have the same number of arguments */
int boxes_inside_ci(const coord min, const int maxx, const int maxy, const int maxz);
int boxes_inside_ic(const int minx, const int miny, const int minz,  const coord max);
#define boxes_inside_4(a, ...) _Generic((a),\
        coord: boxes_inside_ci) \
        int:  boxes_inside_ic) \
    )(__VA_ARGS__)

/* make macro call itself with the number of arguments pasted after it */
#define boxes_inside(...) paste(boxes_inside, get_suffix(__VA_ARGS__))(__VA_ARGS__)
```

The upside of this approach is that you get reasonably readable error messages, for example

- `warning: implicit declaration of function ‘boxes_inside_3’` for the wrong number of arguments, or
- `expected ‘coord {aka const struct <anonymous>}’ but argument is of type ‘int’` if the types are wrong.